# Laravel groupBy doesn't work properly with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel

I have same number of rows with `groupBy` as well without it.

```
$authors = AuthorMask::where('company_id', $user->company_id)
        ->groupBy('id', 'author_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

If I use this:

```
$authors = AuthorMask::where('company_id', $user->company_id)
        ->groupBy('author_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

I get an error.

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "author_masks.id" 
>   must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: select * from "author_masks" where "company_id" = $1 group 
>   b... ^ (SQL: select * from "author_masks" where "company_id" = 1 group
>   by  "author_id" order by "created_at" desc limit 5 offset 0)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to run 2nd query with PostgreSQL, as it requires all fields that are specified in ***SELECT*** list to be part of the ***GROUP BY*** expression.

you can check over [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

Comment: Thank you. But why 1st query doesn't work? Return no errors, just nothing changes (e.g. I have 3 records with author_id = 1 but it returns 3 records instead of 1).